# conversion of unicode string to human readable format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print unicode string but it fails with message

```
File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
```

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-10: character maps to

I am reading the file using encoding as utf-8

```
with open(filename,'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

I am very confused regarding the problem.

Whenever I user logger it dumps the data directly but with I am getting issues with print

I am using mpi4py for the execution.
[image]

this is the language which has the problem

[image]

```
with open(filename,'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
next(f)
next(f)
//logic to extract hashtags from tweets and send to different processes using mpi

// code to gather the tweets from various processes and print
```

Comment: Show us the all code required to reproduce the problem and the full error traceback!

Comment: @KlausD. I cannot share the entire code but I will update the question with the snippets

Comment: Make sure it's a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I tried to explain as deep as I can. its very difficult to produce the code here due to some restrictions on me

Comment: Can you add the logger output as text, so we can copy it? And don't forget the full tracaback,

Comment: Look at the traceback. The `UnicodeEncodeError` exception is raised in `C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py`. Somewhere in your code, either implicitly or explicitly, a string is being encoded as `cp1252` instead of (I assume) `utf-8`. Nobody can help you any more unless you post the offending code.